# Predicates in Java 8

Tags: java, oop, lambda, java-8, predicate

I have a program that analyzes text for certain attributes. The basic structure of the code is the same for all attributes it only varies in one line: `webDataField.containsAttributeXYZ();` as seen here:

```
for (int index = 0; index < fields.size(); index++) {
    WebDataField webDataField = fields.get(index);
    boolean expectedCondition = webDataField.containsAttributeXYZ(); // Varies at this line..

    Double score = evaluateBooleanCondition(actualCondition, expectedCondition);

    WebDataFields fieldName = webDataField.getFieldName();
    ...
}
```

Instead of writing the same code for each condition (& repeating myself in code) I'd like to write the main body of the code once and pass the condition (which evaluates to true or false) to the method.

I am new to `Java Predicate` but if I understand correctly this is exactly the function of predicates in Java.

Does this force me to write each condition in its own class and then have that class implement the `Predicate` interface?

If so, the function (which is previously declared in a class that contains similar functions) will need to be converted to something like:

```
class ContainsAttributeXYZ implements Predicate<Boolean>
```

This would cause the code to become disoriented and trigger a large increase in the number of classes in the program (as every function needs to be converted into a class)

Or did I misunderstand something about how Predicates work in Java? Is there another way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. A `Predicate` does not need to be declared as a class. For example, `Predicate<String> p = (String s) -> s.length() > 5;` will do.

Comment: A `Predicate<Boolean>` doesn't make much sense. You probably want `Predicate<WebDataField>`.

Comment: How is it that you added the [lambda] tag, and yet apparently have no idea what they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example method that takes a `Predicate` as an argument:

```
void processFields(List<WebDataField> fields, Predicate<WebDataField> predicate) {
    for (WebDataField webDataField : fields) {
        boolean expectedCondition = predicate.test(webDataField);
    }
}
```

and you would call it by passing a method reference, like this:

```
processFields(fields, WebDataField::containsAttributeXYZ);
processFields(fields, WebDataField::containsAttributeABC);
```

Where `containsAttributeXYZ` and `containsAttributeABC` are methods of `WebDataField` class that return `boolean`. Or you can create a lambda inline without modifying `WebDataField`. E.g. :

```
processFields(fields, w -> w.getFieldName().length() > 5);
```

You don't need to create a class that implements `Predicate`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new class to create a `Predicate`. This is because Java 8 added a lambda syntax, which you can think of as a shorthand for anonymous inner classes implementing an interface with only one method. Here is an example:

```
Predicate<Boolean> containsXYZ = b -> {
    return !b;
};
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Predicate<Boolean> containsXYZ = new Predicate<Boolean>() {
    public boolean test(Boolean b) {
        return !b;
    }
};
```

If your predicate just returns the result of a single expression, it can be shortened to:

```
Predicate<Boolean> containsXYZ = b -> !b;
```

Alternatively, a function can be a reference to a method:

```
Predicate<Boolean> containsXYZ = MyClass::myMethod; // for static methods, or
Predicate<Boolean> containsXYZ = this::myMethod; // for instance methods
```

This is a one-line predicate that returns true if the input is false, and vice versa. Now, for your use case, you might want something like this:

```
static void checkAttributes(Predicate<WebDataField> containsAttributeXYZ) {
    for (WebDataField webDataField : fields) {
        boolean expectedCondition = containsAttributeXYZ.test(webDataField);
        Double score = evaluateBooleanCondition(actualCondition, expectedCondition);
        WebDataFields fieldName = webDataField.getFieldName();

        ...
    }
}
```

For a thorough explanation of how lambdas work, read the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: That’s a pretty verbose way of writing `b -> !b`.  The braces and return keyword aren’t necessary.

Comment: @VGR Agreed, but I thought it might me more readable to someone from a Java background who has (apparently) never seen lambdas before (i.e. the OP). This way, it looks kind of like a method.